# How to replace dots, spaces and commas with hyphen and avoid double hyphen using php?

Tags: php, regex, string, str-replace

When I replace spaces, dots and commas of a string, it sometimes happens that I get double hyphens.

For example turns `check out the 1. place` into `check-out-the-1--place`

How can I avoid that? I want it to be `check-out-the-1-place` - so that there only is one hyphen between each word.
Here is my code:

```
str_replace([' ', ',', '.','?'], '-', strtolower($pathname));
```

Right now, I know why it returns the double-hyphens, but I don't know how to work around that.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: May be try to call one more str_replace '--' with '-'

Comment: @VitalijsG. How about `---`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I avoid that? I want it to be check-out-the-1-place - so that there only is one hyphen between each word. Here is my code:

Whilst [Mohammad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52532174/3536236) is *nearly* there, here is a more fully working [PCRE regex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) method and explanation as to how it works, so you can use it as you need:

```
$str = trim(strtolower($pathname));
$newStr = preg_replace('/[\s.,-]+/', '-', $str);
```

How this works:

- Match a single character present in the list below `[\s.,-]+`

  - `+` Quantifier Matches between **one and unlimited** times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - `\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to [`\r\n\t\f\v`])
  - `.,-` matches a single character in the list `.,-` (case sensitive)
  - The dash `-` must come at the *end* of the `[]` set.

**Results:**

> This: check out the 1. place

Becomes:

`check-out-the-1-place`

And

> This: check out the - 1. place

Becomes

`check-out-the-1-place`

---

## Further:

I would go further and assuming you are using this for a URL slug ([a what?!](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205814578-Changing-URL-slugs)); strip out *all* non-alphanumeric characters from the string and replace with a single `-` as per typical website slugs.

```
 $newStr = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', '-', $str);
```

How this works:

- Match a single character **NOT** (`^`) present in the list below `[a-z0-9]+`

  - `+` Quantifier Matches between **one and unlimited** times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - `a-z` a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)
  - `0-9` a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
  - The `i` at the end indicates the judgements are **case In-sensitive**.

Example:

> check out - the no.! 1. Place

Becomes:

`check-out-the-1-Place`

Comment: Thanks alot, this is perfect! :-) Even though Mohammads answer is very good too

Comment: @ST80 great, glad to help! You can give Mohammad a +1 as well `;-)`

Comment: +1 for just perfect answer, but i suggest @Martin that you should `trim($str)` before replacing hyphens, otherwise it can add hyphens at the start or end of the string.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `preg_replace()` instead and user regex to selecting multiple specific character.

```
$newStr = preg_replace("/[\s.,]+/", "-", $str)
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/jDkYf)